# NodeJS Mongoose Not Save Data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, odm, mongoose-schema

My system will create around 30 collection for every hour. My server get thousands request for one hour. I have big data and multiple collections. And i use MongoDB-NodeJS for saving data.

The modelControl function of pariteModel class at the paritemodel.js -**as the below codes**- i do check if this schema is created before. And i will create schema or use created schema.

First collections creating and saving data to MongoDB. But when create another collections it's not doing. For example:

EURJPY_20160107_**16** collection is created but EURJPY_20160107_**17** collection is not create. I have check **mongoose.models at modelparite.js** EURJPY_20160107_17 is created but instance created from EURJPY_20160107_17 Schema not saved to database.

My server files like this:

**app.js** file is my bootstrap file:

```js
var http = require('http'),
dispatcher = require('httpdispatcher');

require('./mongo.js');

function handleRequest(request, response){
    try {
        dispatcher.dispatch(request, response);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

server.listen(3663, function(){
        console.log('listening the port: ' + 3663);
});
```

This is **mongo.js** which i call in app.js. This file uses for save data to mongodb:

```js
var dispatcher = require('httpdispatcher'),
url = require('url'),
moment = require('moment'),
md = moment().format("YYYYMMDD_HH"),
myModel = require('./modelparite.js');

dispatcher.onGet('/mongo', function(req, res){

        var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
        // This is collection name. Output like this: USDTRY_20160107_16
        var colName = url_parts.query.symbol + '_' + md;

        var tarih = new Date();

        var pariteModel = myModel.returnModel(colName);
        var yeniParite = new pariteModel({
                symbol: url_parts.query.symbol,
                bid: url_parts.query.bid,
                ask: url_parts.query.ask,
                timeup: moment(tarih).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
        });

        yeniParite.save(function (err, data) {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                console.dir(data,true);
        });

        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end();
});
```

And this is my model **modelparite.js** file which i call in mongo.js. This file uses to create schema with Mongoose:

```js
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    helper = require('./helper.js');
    require('mongoose-double')(mongoose);

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/forex');

    var pariteModel = {

            pariteSchema: "",

            initSchema: function(){

                    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
                    this.pariteSchema = new Schema({
                            symbol: String,
                            bid: mongoose.Schema.Types.Double,
                            ask: mongoose.Schema.Types.Double,
                            timeup: Date
                    });
            },

            modelControl: function(modelName){
                    if(mongoose.models[modelName]){
                            return true;
                    }
                    return false;
            },

            returnModel: function(modelName){

                    modelName = helper.whichParity(modelName);
                    //console.log(modelName);

                    if(this.modelControl(modelName)){
                            //console.log(mongoose.model(modelName));
                            return mongoose.model(modelName);
                    }else{
                            this.initSchema();
                            return mongoose.model(modelName, this.pariteSchema);
                    }
            },
    }

    module.exports = pariteModel;
```